# How can I count the number of entries of a column based on the distinct entries of another column

Tags: perl, r, aggregate

My data in a file is like below with multiple columns:

```
A                B             

Tiger         Animal         
Parrot        Bird
Lion          Animal
Elephant      Animal
Crow          Bird
Horse         Animal
Man           Human
Dog           Animal
```

I want to find the number of entries in column A corresponding to distinct entries in column B. If possible in R or may be a perl script for this.

Output as:

```
Animal 5
Bird   2
Human  1
```

Moreover, if possible to find out if the entries in column A has been repeated for the distinct entries in column B like

```
A              B   
Tiger         Animal         
Tiger         Animal
```

Comment: user744121, read the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [modify your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6623598/edit) accordingly. Use real text. The text on the image cannot be copied/pasted, you erect barriers that make it difficult for interested people to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tapply` from base R will solve this nicely.

```
with(anm, tapply(A, B, function(x) length(unique(x))))
```

Comment: +1 This is the cleanest way to do this IMHO, but I think he wants: something even simpler, namely `with(anm, tapply(A, B, length))`

Comment: with(anm, tapply(A, B, length)) seems to count all the occurrences, is there any way to get unique count? Also 
What does 'x' imply here in
with(anm, tapply(A, B, function(x) length(unique(x))))

Comment: @user744121 it's an argument name for the function (without name). You could also do `fun.name <- function(x) length(unique(x))` and then pass `fun.name` to the `FUN` argument of `tapply`. Richie's solution is a sort of a short cut.

Comment: @Roman: I used your answer in a sample file and it worked fine. But my file has around 9 million rows and its taking forever to run this code in R. I think that it takes a single row and compares it with the rest ot 9 million rows, thats why its talking so long. Any idea on this?

Comment: @user744121 which step is taking "ages"? `colSums` or `table`?

Comment: @Roman: I've run this command on my whole dataset: 
with(anm, tapply(A, B, function(x) length(unique(x)))
If I run this command to an object with say only 15 rows, the output is obtained in a few seconds, but when it is run on an object with 9 million rows it takes "ages" and I still haven't got the output.

Comment: @user744121 I would try by subsetting a small sample of your data (let's say 10000 rows), run the function, repeat with a bigger sample... That way you could get an idea of how long it really takes to do 9 million lines.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution done in R. Is this what you were looking for?

```
> anm <- data.frame(A = c("Tiger", "Parrot", "Lion", "Elephant", "Crow", "Horse", "Man", "Dog", "Tiger"),
+       B = c("Animal", "Bird", "Animal", "Animal", "Bird", "Animal", "Human", "Animal", "Animal"))
> anm
         A      B
1    Tiger Animal
2   Parrot   Bird
3     Lion Animal
4 Elephant Animal
5     Crow   Bird
6    Horse Animal
7      Man  Human
8      Dog Animal
9    Tiger Animal
> (col.anm <- colSums(table(anm)))
Animal   Bird  Human 
     6      2      1 
> table(anm)
          B
A          Animal Bird Human
  Crow          0    1     0
  Dog           1    0     0
  Elephant      1    0     0
  Horse         1    0     0
  Lion          1    0     0
  Man           0    0     1
  Parrot        0    1     0
  Tiger         2    0     0 # you can see how many times entry from A comes up
```

*EDIT*

To get the desired output format as noted in the comment, wrap your result in a `data.frame`.

```
> data.frame(col.anm)
       col.anm
Animal       6
Bird         2
Human        1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, I just need the counts for Animal, Bird and Humans like <br/>
Animal 5 <br/>
Bird   2 <br/>
Human  1

Comment: @user744121 I've added an EDIT that should do what you were looking for.

Comment: This isn't picking up the repeated Tiger value.  I think the questioner wants the number of unique entries in column A for each element of column B.  Try `colSums(table(anm) > 0)`.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is in R, you can use `table()` to get what you need. First some example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c("tiger","parrot","lion","tiger"),B=c("animal","bird","animal","animal"))
```

Then we can get counts of `B` with:

```
table(dat$B)
```

and counts of co-occurance with:

```
table(dat)
```

To get the table you specified we can use the `plyr` package:

```
library("plyr")
tab <- ddply(dat,.(A,B),nrow)
tab[tab$V1>1,]
      A      B V1
3 tiger animal  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I get the full data structure in the file, but if you're on UNIX:

`tr -s ' ' | sort -u | awk '{ print $2}' | sort | uniq -c`

```
5 Animal
2 Bird
1 Human
```

The above works, even if I add this line: "Tiger Animal" at the end, because of the first sort -u.

The tr -s squeezes out multiple blank spaces (so the sort commands act as expected)

Comment: I am very new to awk. Could you please explain what the command does from the beginning and step wise to the end? Thanks in advance.

Comment: where do I give the input file in your solution to make it work

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else comes by here, here are a couple more approaches that work.

```
myout   <-  lapply(split(anm,list(anm$B)),function(x)
            list(length(unique(x[,"A"])),x[duplicated(x),"A"])
        )
unlist(sapply(myout,function(x)x[1])) # counts in each category
sapply(myout,function(x)x[-1]) # list of duplicated names
```

or....

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(anm,key="B")
mydt[,.N,by=key(mydt)]
mydt[,.N,by="B,A"][N>1]
```

where....

```
anm = read.table(textConnection(
    "Tiger    Animal         
    Parrot    Bird
    Lion      Animal
    Elephant  Animal
    Crow      Bird
    Horse     Animal
    Man       Human
    Dog       Animal
    Tiger     Animal"))
names(anm) <- c("A","B")
```

EDIT: Edited in response to comment by Matthew Dowle (author of data.table).

Comment: I mention it only because Richie's method was too slow for me (with only 500k obs, it did not finish within my patience threshold). This "lapply(split(...))" combination seems to show up quite often in the questions I've been looking through on this site.

Comment: For duplicates, try `mydt[,.N,by="B,A"][N>1]`. You don't _have_ to set a key first, btw. Unkeyed by (known as _ad hoc by_) is pretty fast and often more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the first easily with `awk`:

```
awk '{ myarray[$2]++ } END { for ( key in myarray ) { print key ": " myarray[key] } }' FILE
```

The second is a bit trickier... ( http://ideone.com/xdKcs )

```
awk '{ myarray[$2]++ ; myarray2[$2, $1]++ } 
     END { for ( key in myarray ) { print key ": " myarray[key] } 
           print
           print "Duplicates: "
           for (key in myarray2) { 
               split(key,sep,SUBSEP)
               if (myarray2[sep[1], sep[2]]>1)
                   { print sep[1] ": " sep[2] " " myarray2[sep[1], sep[2]]
     }}}' FILE
```

Comment: both the command gives same results i.e it counts the repeated entries also and gives something like
Animal       6
Bird         2
Human        1
 counting both the repeated entries 'Tiger Animal', i wanted the count to ignore the entry which has already been counted

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using the `plyr` package in R.

```
mydf = read.table(textConnection(
"Tiger    Animal         
Parrot    Bird
Lion      Animal
Elephant  Animal
Crow      Bird
Horse     Animal
Man       Human
Dog       Animal
Tiger     Animal"))

library(plyr)
ddply(mydf, .(V2), summarize, V3 = length(V1))

    V2    V3
1 Animal  6
2   Bird  2
3  Human  1

ddply(mydf, .(V2, V1), summarize, V3 = length(V1))

    V2         V1  V3
1 Animal      Dog  1
2 Animal Elephant  1
3 Animal    Horse  1
4 Animal     Lion  1
5 Animal    Tiger  2
6   Bird     Crow  1
7   Bird   Parrot  1
8  Human      Man  1
```

EDIT. Adds the names of animals in each category

```
 ddply(mydf, .(V2), summarize, 
    V3 = length(V1), 
    V4 = do.call("paste", as.list(unique(V1))))

      V2 V3                            V4
1 Animal  6 Tiger Lion Elephant Horse Dog
2   Bird  2                   Parrot Crow
3  Human  1                           Man
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. I want the counts only like
Animal 5
Bird   2
Human  1

Comment: Sorry for the last comment, I think the first one is the solution I was looking for. 
Also is it possible to add the name of animals along side the counts in the first output?

Comment: Same issue as with Roman's answer.  It should be counting unique animals.  `ddply(mydf, .(V2), summarize, V3 = length(unique(V1)))`.

Comment: @Richie. not sure if that is what the OP wants. note that both @Roman and me have added an extra row to the OP's dataset so that there are two rows with `Tiger`.

Comment: Actually, the data above is hypothetical data and my actual data is huge and something else, but I wanted to explain with the help of this simple concept.Its clear and okay that both of you have added an extra rows which makes it easier to explain what I am looking for actually. There are two things:
1. Number of unique entries from V1 that fall under the distinct entries from V2. example - only counting tiger once
2. If tiger is repeated then to display that the tiger is repeated 'n' times.

Answer (score 1):

If you're more comfortable with SQL, here's a very short solution using the `sqldf` package in R:

```
anm <- data.frame(A = c("Tiger", "Parrot", "Lion", "Elephant", "Crow", "Horse", "Man", "Dog", "Tiger"),
      B = c("Animal", "Bird", "Animal", "Animal", "Bird", "Animal", "Human", "Animal", "Animal"))

library(sqldf)      
sqldf("select B,count(distinct A) tot from anm group by B")

sqldf("select B,A,count(*) num from anm group by B,A HAVING num > 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl (`strict` and `warnings` implied.)

```
my ( %uniq, %count_for );
# here $fh = some input source
while ( <$fh> ) {
    s/^\s+//; # trim left
    s/\s*$//; # trim right (and chomp)
    # This split allows for spaces between words in a single column
    # allows also for tab-delimited record
    my @cols = split /(?:\t|\s{2,})/;
    # Normalize the text and test for uniqueness:
    #
    # By these manipulations: 
    #     Tiger   Animal
    # matches
    #     Tiger      Animal
    # for any column irregularities
    next if $uniq{join('-',@cols)};

    # count occurrence.
    $count_for{$cols[1]}++;
}
```

Comment: I put my file on the second line $fh = "sample.txt" and executed the script as perl script.pl > output.txt, but the output shows nothing

Comment: @user744121, output is not really part of the algorithm. The easiest way to see what's in `%count_for` is to add the following after the loop:`use Data::Dumper;print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ \%count_for ], [ '*count_for' ] ), "\n";`

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Slurp qw(slurp);

exit unless $ARGV[0];

my @data = slurp($ARGV[0]);
my (%h);

for (@data) {
  chomp;
  map { next if /^(A|B)$/; $h{$_}++ } split ' ', $_;
}

map { print $_, ": ", $h{$_}, "\n" } keys %h;
```

usage:

```
$ perl script.pl columns.txt
```